# Can't access Website through Wireguard, only works through SOCKS proxy

Tags: google-chrome, big-sur

My site is running on a server and is only reachable through Wireguard. I can access it perfectly fine on Arch and Android. However, accessing it from MacOS fails, giving `ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED`. To access it, I need to connect through the server through a SOCKS proxy. I should note that I can access it through HTTP, but not HTTPS. Other sites work fine. However, any sites with bad certificates, like `https://self-signed.badssl.com/` fail similarly as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out -- another VPN I had set up blocks all connections that do not use their set of trusted certificates.